# Matching dict key to text file and returning Test Pass/fail

Tags: dictionary, pattern-matching, string-matching, testcase

I'm a novice at Python, and am currently working on a small test case assignment where I am to find and match the dictionary keys to a small text file, and see if the keys are present in the text file.

As follows, the dictionary goes:

> dict = {"description, translation": "test_translation(serial,",
>           "unit": "test_unit(",}

The text in text file, henceforth called "requirement.txt" as follows:

> The description shall display the translation of XXX.
>   The unit shall be hidden.
>   The value is read from the file "version.txt".

To the key, I am to find and match if they are present or absent - a match should return a "test pass", no match would return a skip.

Keys from dictionary are to be sorted to a list, then iterated and matched to text. (Values from dictionary are to be sorted to a seperate list and iterated over a seperate file, to which I shall not delve into it here.)

This is the code that I currently have (and stuck):

```
list = sorted(key_words.keys(), key=lambda d: d[0])
with open('C:/Users-------/requirement.txt', 'r') as outfile:
    lines = outfile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == '':
            continue
        line_strings = line.split(' ')
        for word in list:
            if word in line:
                print("Test Pass")
                print(word)
                break
            else:
                print("Test Fail")
        print(line + "\n")
```

Result currently obtained:

```
Test Fail
Test Pass
display
The description shall display the translation of XXX.

Test Fail
Test Fail
Test Fail
Test Pass
unit
The unit shall be hidden.

Test Fail
Test Fail
Test Fail
Test Fail
The value is read from the file "version.txt".
```

Using the current code which I have, (and I am stuck), running the code returned multiple times of "Test pass" and "Test fail", suggesting that the keys are iterated multiple times over each line and the results returned for each multiple iteration.

I am stuck at two fronts:

1. After seperating the key into a list, how to order them in the sequence of "description, translation", "unit)?
2. How to modify the code so as to ensure that result is returned once as "Test pass" or "test fail"

Results should ideally return in the following format:

Ideal outcome:

```
('Text:', "The description shall display the translation of XXX.
('Key:', 'description, translation')
Test Pass

('Text:', 'The unit shall be hidden.')
('Key:', 'unit')
Test Pass

('Text:', 'The value is read from the file "version.txt".')
('Key:', (none))
Test Fail
```

For your kind enlightenment please, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
list = sorted(key_words.keys(), key=lambda d: d[0])
with open('C:/Users-------/requirement.txt', 'r') as outfile:
    lines = outfile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == '':
            continue

        # Create an empty list which will contain all the word that match
        words_found = []

        for word in list:
            # if the word match then add it to the list words_found
            if word in line:
                words_found.append(word)

        print("(\'Text:\',\"{}\"")' ".format(line))
        print("(\'Keys:\',\"{}\"")' ".format(words_found))

        # if the list of words found it's not empty then the test passed
        if(words_found):
            print("Test Passed")
        else:
            print("Test Failed")
```

the idea is to create a list of the words founds and then print them all
I'm using the [format](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html) Operation and you can find a guide on how to use it [here](https://pyformat.info/). And the line `if(words_found):` check if the list is empty.

### Additional Notes

In this case, you won't need it but if you wanted to solve only the second point you can use the `for else` statement as explained  [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html)

> ## 4.4 break and continue Statements, and else Clauses on Loops
>
> Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement.

Reducing by one tab the indentation the else of your if statement it became the else of the for statement so it will be executed only if the for never had a break the problem is solved.

```
list = sorted(key_words.keys(), key=lambda d: d[0])
with open('C:/Users-------/requirement.txt', 'r') as outfile:
    lines = outfile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == '':
            continue
        line_strings = line.split(' ')
        for word in list:
            if word in line:
                print(word)
                print("Test Pass")
                break
        else:
            print("Test Fail")
        print(line + "\n")
```

## Edit

To split the key into description and translation we just have to split the two word at the comma with the builtin function [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

```
list = sorted(key_words.keys(), key=lambda d: d[0])
with open('C:/Users-------/requirement.txt', 'r') as outfile:
    lines = outfile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == '':
            continue

        # Create an empty list which will contain all the word that match
        words_found = []

        for word in list:
            description, translation = word.split(",")
            # if the word match then add it to the list words_found
            if description in line:
                words_found.append(description)

        print("(\'Text:\',\"{}\"")' ".format(line))
        print("(\'Keys:\',\"{}\"")' ".format(words_found))

        # if the list of words found it's not empty then the test passed
        if(words_found):
            print("Test Passed")
        else:
            print("Test Failed")
```

Comment: A great thanks to your advice! While the code works, however, I have one issue that need further advice:

As I have pointed out, "description, translation" is the key that is to be matched with the sentence text, "The description shall display the translation of XXX.". Since the words "description" and "translation" are in the sentence, they should return a "Test pass", but instead a "Test fail" result come back.

Comment: From what I see, python recognises "description, translation" as one big element in one key, but they are actually two seperate elements (words) in one key. The "word" function that you have posted doesn't seem to be compatible for this issue, perhaps is there any other syntax (besides "word") that can be utilised in the code instead?

For your kind advice again, thank you!

Comment: yep sorry I didn't get that from the question, editing it rn.

Comment: Hi, good morning!
I've tried the modified code which you have added --

Comment: for word in list:
            description, translation = word.split(",")
            # if the word match then add it to the list words_found
            if description in line:
                words_found.append(description)

Comment: It returns the following message:<br>
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Er...you have any idea as to why the error message pops up?
(PS: I'm running on Python 2.7)
Hope to hear from you soon, thank you!